# Error running script: "ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']"

Tags: python, numpy

I know there are a lot of similar questions to this but I have tried all the solutions I could find and none of them seem to work.

I have a python script that I run every day through task scheduler (Windows 10) that includes the lines

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

For about 2 weeks this script ran on schedule with no problems and then stopped working (I may have updated something at this point but I can't remember). Specifically, it no longer works when run directly through the console i.e. `>python C:\dir\script.py`. But it still works fine if I load the script in Spyder and run it there.

The error it throws is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 15, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\user1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

I have C:\Users\user1\Anaconda3\ included in the system PATH environment variable. I have also reinstalled numpy multiple times. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `conda`, this might come from the fact that conda has change the way it is activated in its latest version on windows. In particular, it has trouble loading DLLs when you are not in an activated conda environment.

By running your command `python C:\dir\script.py` from an active conda env (using `conda activate` for the base env for instance), you should see this issue disapear.

Comment: For more infomation, see this link: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment

Comment: Tried that and I get no more numpy error but now it seems to have problems finding scipy: ````File "C:\Users\user1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 14, in <module>
    import scipy.sparse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'````

Comment: Are you sure you installed `scipy` in the conda env you are using? This seems weird if you have no trouble running other commands.

Comment: I thought i did but i reinstalled scipy and now it works. Thanks! For clarification, packages installed by running ````!pip install package```` on the Spyder console are now confined to the Spyder env only?

Comment: The package that are installed via `!pip install package` should be available in the conda environement once it is activated. However, they might become not available if the version of python installed by conda changes -- for instance from `3.6` to `3.7` -- as they are installed in the specific site-package of version `X.Y`, _ie_ `/path/to/conda/lib/pythonX.Y/site-package/`